# Div with position absolute extends bottom scrolling

Tags: html, css

The yellow box at the top works like it should. The one at the bottom does not. The scrolling should stop at the end of the footer, here as black line (and also not extend to the right).

Of course, there could be a way to to this with graphics.
Is there a solution with CSS?

```css
#mainwrapper {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.top-ci-colorbox {
  position: absolute;
  top: -135px;
  right: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 2000px;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: rotate(-3.5deg);
}

.bottom-ci-colorbox {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -135px;
  left: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 2000px;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: rotate(-3.5deg);
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 1000px;
  top: 0;
}

footer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainwrapper">
  <div class="top-ci-colorbox"></div>
  <header>Navigation Here</header>
  <main>
    ...
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

  </main>
  <footer>Footer Here. Scrolling should stop at black line</footer>
  <div class="bottom-ci-colorbox"></div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h25d5b8z/12/)

Comment: Your .bottom-ci-colorbox div is outside the footer but you want the footer to be the end, thats a bit of an odd setup, if you had the box inside the footer their would be a way using overflow:hidden however if you are just trying to use that div to create a triangle then your better to lookup CSS Triangle and absolutely position a triangle in the footer.

Comment: Nickfmc I guess you are right. But can you tell me: Why is the behaviour at the bottom different than at the top. The top div also exeeds the page. And I only get a scrollbar to the right, not to the left, only page overflow at the bottom and not at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading several topics about css overflow problems here on stackoverflow, I found the solution by myself. It is difficult to use overflow on only one axis because of unexpected behaviour.

Insted the #mainwrapper div needs to be wrapped in another div. This div comes with overflow: hidden.

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
     <div id="mainwrapper">
     ...
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code. hope it will help you

```css
#mainwrapper {
   max-width: 100%;
   margin: auto;
   padding-top: 100px;
   position: relative;
   overflow-y: hidden;
}
#mainwrapper:before,
#mainwrapper:after{
  content : "";
  transform: rotate(-3.5deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: -60px;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: rotate(-3.5deg);
  
}
#mainwrapper:after{
  top: auto;
  bottom: -60px;
}
   
   header {
     position: fixed;
     max-width: 1000px;
     top: 0;
   }
   
   footer {
     position: relative;
     z-index: 10;
     border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   }
```

```html
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>

      </head>
      <body>
         <div id="mainwrapper">
            <div class="top-ci-colorbox"></div>
            <header>Navigation Here</header>
            <main>
               Is it possible to let the bottom box behave like the top one, so that the scrolling ends after reaching the footer and most part of the box is not beeing displayed. The same with the right scrolling, which is extended by the bottom box (and left scrolling not by the top one).
               <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
               <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
               <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
               <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

            </main>
            <footer>Footer Here. Scrolling should stop at black line</footer>
            <div class="bottom-ci-colorbox"></div>
         </div>

      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: A little explanation about why your code works and why the OPs doesn't would make this answer better.  Consider adding one.

Comment: This results in the same problem. The :after element is handled in the same way like my position absolute div.

Comment: Yes I have just removed some css and div code to make code little shorter

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,body,#mainwrapper{
  height:100%;
}
body{
  margin-bottom:0;
}
#mainwrapper {
   max-width: 1000px;
   margin: auto;
   padding-top: 100px;
   position: relative;
   overflow:hidden;
   box-sizing:border-box;
}
main{
      height: calc( 100% - 19px );
}
   .top-ci-colorbox {
      position: absolute;
      top: -135px;
      right: 0;
      height: 200px;
      width: 2000px;
      background-color: yellow;
      transform: rotate(-3.5deg);
   }

   .bottom-ci-colorbox {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -135px;
      left: 0;
      height: 200px;
      width: 2000px;
      background-color: yellow;
      transform: rotate(-3.5deg);
   }
   
   header {
     position: fixed;
     max-width: 1000px;
     top: 0;
   }
   
   footer {
     position: relative;
     z-index: 10;
     
     border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
         <div id="mainwrapper">
            <div class="top-ci-colorbox"></div>
            <header>Navigation Here</header>
            <main>
               Is it possible to let the bottom box behave like the top one, so that the scrolling ends after reaching the footer and most part of the box is not beeing displayed. The same with the right scrolling, which is extended by the bottom box (and left scrolling not by the top one).
               <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
               <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

            </main>
            <footer>Footer Here. Scrolling should stop at black line</footer>
            <div class="bottom-ci-colorbox"></div>
         </div>

    </body>
  </html>
```

Check in Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h25d5b8z/28/

First up all you must need to set height 100% to html,body and the main element.If we absolute any item ,we must need to add property overflow:hidden to it's parent element.In this case we need to add overflow:hidden to #main-wrapper.We also need to set height to main tag element

Comment: A little explanation about why your code works and why the OPs doesn't would make this answer better.  Consider adding one.

Comment: add it to your answer (by editing it) - not the comments :/

Comment: In this case we solved the problem on the top-bottm axis, but at the same time did an unwanted change. Go back to my example and make the render windows larger than 1000px. You will see, that the yellow boxes overflow the mainwrapper to the left and right and this is correct. only the overflow at the bottom is a problem AND the scrollbar to the right. If I set the overflow on your example only on one axis, I get a scroll bar within the mainwrapper. overflow-y: hidden; does not work.